# Xamarin.Droid Binding Visibility Converter using MvxVisibility wont work

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have tree parts of layout in my file.axml

I wanna show/hide some of them based on a property in my viewmodel

My property is an enumerator, and Iam using an converter to return the visibility based on the enum.

Iam using the type "MvxVisibility" in the core, but for some reason, the android is not understand the return type (visibility)

Here is my android binding:

```
<LinearLayout
        local:MvxBind="Visibility RedeemCodeState, Converter=RedeemStateToVisibility, ConverterParameter=0"
```

Here is my converter (core)
 public class RedeemStateToVisibilityConverter :

```
MvxValueConverter<RedeemCodeState, MvxVisibility>
    {
        protected override MvxVisibility Convert(RedeemCodeState mark, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            switch (mark)
            {
                case RedeemCodeState.RedeemCodeSubmit:
                    if (parameter.ToString() == "0")
                        return MvxVisibility.Visible;
                    return MvxVisibility.Collapsed;

                case RedeemCodeState.AudiosSelection:
                    if (parameter.ToString() == "1")
                        return MvxVisibility.Visible;
                    return MvxVisibility.Collapsed;

                case RedeemCodeState.Confirmation:
                    if (parameter.ToString() == "2")
                        return MvxVisibility.Visible;
                    return MvxVisibility.Collapsed;

                default:
                    return MvxVisibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my ViewModel (core):

```
public partial class RedeemCodeViewModel
    {
        private RedeemCodeState _redeemCodeState = 0;
        public RedeemCodeState RedeemCodeState
        {
            get { return _redeemCodeState; }
            set
            {
                _redeemCodeState = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => RedeemCodeState);
            }
        }

        public RedeemCodeViewModel(string code)
        {

            RedeemCode = code;

        }
    }

    public enum RedeemCodeState
    {
        RedeemCodeSubmit = 0,
        AudiosSelection = 1,
        Confirmation = 2
    }
```

What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Value converters are meant to convert *portable* values to platform specific values. *MvxVisibility* is a portable type.

You need to add the Visibility plugins to both your Core and Droid projects. You can call multiple value converters in your binding.

```
 local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(RedeemStateToVisibility(RedeemCodeState, 0))"
```

> Note: I'm using Tibet binding syntax

This calls your value converter to convert your code state to a MvxVisibility value. We finally call Visibility value converter to convert that to the Android visibility value.

Comment: There are also simpler `Visible` `bool` properties on most platforms - and there's a visibility converter base class too - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/Plugins/Visibility/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility/MvxBaseVisibilityValueConverter.cs :)

Comment: Hi Kiliman, but how do I add the visibility plugin to core and droid? Do you have a link showing that? Thank you so much.

Comment: Just search for "mvvmcross visibility" on NuGet. You'll see the plugins.

Comment: I did it, I installed the Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility package and also changed the converter to be of type: MvxBaseVisibilityValueConverter...  I get the convert to calculate the corret visibility but the android view doent respect the value, it get always "visible" even when the converter returns Visibility.Collapsed...

Comment: Did you install in your Android project? Did you look at the log output to see if Mvx is outputting any errors?